# Making exe-file in c portable - static linking

Tags: c, windows, exe, static-linking

I have made an app in c with a GUI - implementing the GTK lib. Now I want to make this exe-file portable to other window-computers. At the moment this is not possible because the program is dependent of gtk libfiles (for instance libgobject-2.0-0.dll) and my question is:

How do I make this exe-file portable to other window computers? I have heard that the simplest way is to use static-linking. But what is static linking and how do I use it in this context?

*If you have other tips - those are also welcome.* Its all about making this app portable to other window computers.

Comment: You can copy the DLL over, or follow the instruction in the question you duplicated. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @ixe013 - thanks!!! But how could I just copy over the dll-files? Isn't the path to the gtk3/bin-folder fixed after compiling?

Comment: No, it is not fixed. [Windows search for them at runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: If you can "port" one file from one machine to another then you can port two or more.  They don't weigh much.  Users expect a single exe called setup.exe.